# Access USB CDC ACM device from UWP via interop through C DLL

Tags: c#, uwp, usb, interop

I suspect the answer to this is "stop what you're doing," but I promise I have moderately good reasons.

I have a C# interop library that wraps a JLink dll and works fine.  However, I would now like to use this library from a UWP app (because it's the only decent way of dealing with BLE in Windows, if you must know).  Everything works fine, except when the dll attempts to enumerate attached probes, I get back zero probes. I suspect this is because UWP is trying to protect me from the dangerous USB devices and somehow preventing port enumeration (CDC is what JLink uses to talk to attached probes) from taking place.

I've tried various combinations of `DeviceCapability` permissions withing the UWP manifest, but I don't really know if those would have any bearing on an interop'd dll (seems unlikely).  Does anyone know if there's a way of giving myself permission for this or is this a dead end?